# Testing disputes on facebook instant games purchases

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-instant-games, facebook-payments

Does anybody of you test Disputes for Instant Games in-app-purchases?

I'm currently working on some Facebook Messenger Instant Game. We provided simple purchases, but i have no idea how to test disputes on it. 
On Facebook Canvas its really easy thing and we provided it previously in other our game. But on IG we don't have any options to create webhook or dispute test purchase

According to this article: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games_payments/testing/ we would be able to create dispute using this https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/146600035918755 or this https://secure.facebook.com/settings?tab=payments&section=history&env=external link.

But first does not show me testing purchases and second just doesn't work.
Is there any different way to test it?

Answer (score 0):

The link you have is correct:
https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/146600035918755?env=external

But additional parameter is needed env=external

This works for me